# how can i solve upsell product appear same due to full page cache in enterprise edition?

Tags: full-page-cache, ee-1.12

I have an issue in my upsell product block,display same product when reload the page.This problem is due to full page cache. can any one have idea , how can i solve this issue.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to help clarify an answer for you? Please update your question if you have more information that can help us close this out.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as 'hole punching' and it's fairly simple to do.

There are 2 methods to accomplish this:

**The Easy Way:**

If it's an upsell block, the block is already hole-punched for you by the EE FPC module. This is important, as the hole-punch configured requires that the name of the block and the base block itself are correctly named:

```
<block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block>
<name>product.info.upsell</name>
```

If your block is not of type `catalog/product_list_upsell` or you have named (not aliased/"as") it something other than `product.info.upsell` you may have unexpected results.

**The Less-Easy Way:**

You need to create your own hole-punch. This is a 3-step process.

- Create a new module. Insert the following into `etc/cache.xml`:

  catalog/product_list_upsell
              your.block.name
              CATALOG_PRODUCT_LIST_UPSELL
              YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Container_ProductListUpsell
              86400

Ensure that `<name>` and `<block>` accurately reflect the block class name/type for your upsell block.

Now, create a new model in `Model/Container/ProductListUpsell`.

(To future Googlers - you'll want to create a page container model - its superclass may differ in your specific version).

```
<?php

class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Container_ProductListUpsell extends 
Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract {

protected function _renderBlock()
    {
        if (Mage::registry('current_product')) {
            $block = $this->_getPlaceHolderBlock();
            return $block->toHtml();
        }

        return '';
    }

}
```

What the above does is ensure that if we're in a product view scope and `Mage::registry('current_product')` exists, we render the block.

---

**Copyright Notice**

I'm hesitant to re-post the contents of `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_CatalogProductList` here as there is still a discussion about what is copacetic with regard to posting source code from EE happening over in Meta. If you have a copy of 1.12EE available, check out that `_renderBlock` method for the full details of how it determines the current product and loads it into the registry.